# Display custom string in debugger variables

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

I have a class with an overridden `toString()` method. It looks like this:

```
public class Foo {

    private int debugInfo;

    /* some code */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "some-string";
    }
}
```

In debug tab in Android Studio, in 'Variables', it's represented as text from `toString`:
[image: debugger view]

Is it possible to have a custom message for the debugger to display in 'Variables'? I want to see the `debugInfo` field value instead of the output from `toString`, without having to click on the 'expand' arrow.

I know an analog exists in C# - it is the [`[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute):

```
[DebuggerDisplay("info = {debugInfo}")]
public class Foo 
{ 
    private int debugInfo;
}
```

Is there something similar for Java/Android?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722271/intellij-change-tostring-for-debug-mode-variables-view

Answer (score 3):

When you debug, change `toString()` like the following, and then you can change it back to whatever you like afterwards!

```
public class Foo {

    private int debugInfo;

    /* some code */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return debugInfo;
    }
}
```