# IntelliJ change toString for debug mode (variables view)

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

If I overload `toString()`, the debugger in IntelliJ will show me the result from `Object.toString()` near the relevant object in the variables tab.

If `toString` is overloaded with: `return "Test1: This is toString overload";`:

[image]

Sometimes, what I want to see in debug isn't the same as the general `toString` overload. I know it's possible to set another expression for a specific type/class/etc, but only from the settings.

Is there a way to (globally) set an arbitrary function name that will take precedence over `toString` when such function exists?

For example:
If `Object.toDebuggerString()` exists, use it; otherwise, use `Object.toString()`.

```
class Test1 {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test1";
    }
}

class Test2 {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test2";
    }

    public String toDebuggerString() {
        return "Testing debugging mode";
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you can define [Java data type renderers](https://kamilszymanski.github.io/custom-type-renderers-in-intellij-idea-debugger/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the other answers, I got an idea to create a **static class that will supply the correct *debug string* for the debugger**.

So I created such class, which decreases the number of steps needed to configure those data views, and makes it more flexible and comfortable.

## The steps

1. Set a constant expression for `Objects` in the debug customized data views. <sup>[*]</sup>
2. Throw the package/class I made near your code
3. Create `toDebugString()` methods for the relevant data types, and the class will supply it if exists. Otherwise, if `toString()` is overridden, it will use it; and if not, it will use the default `Object.toString()`.

<sup>[*]</sup> *This step needs to be done only once, since IntelliJ keeps this in the global settings.*

## Screenshots

[image]
[image]

## How to get it, and more examples

Publicly available on my GitLab - [IntelliJ-CustomDebugDataView](https://gitlab.com/arieljannai/IntelliJ-CustomDebugDataView)

## Advantages

1. No need to explicitly set a data view for each different data type we're working with.
2. The data view is the same for all objects and so it's easy to track and control what you want to see.
3. Minimal change to the code if you want to use it (one method).

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own.

```
interface Debuggable {
    String toDebugString();
}
```

then in right click a variable in the debugger -> Customize Data Views -> Java Type Renderer -> + -> type: Debuggable

It will do this for any object of this type for any program in future.

Comment: Sounds like the direction I'm looking for - thanks! Will look at it soon

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I eventually came up with another solution that from my point of view is more comfortable and nice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can press `Alt-F8` and evaluate any arbitrary expression. For example, type `test1.toDebuggerString()` and press `Ctrl-Enter`. Then press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to add its value to the watch window.

Note the triangle to the left of the variable name. This is much more useful than just a different `toDebuggerString()` method. You click on the triangle to view the values of all member fields.

Comment: Thanks! I'm familiar with those methods, and a lot of times when I debug I have a lot of variables and it's more time consuming and confusing to enter the evaluation window or expand each variable. So I'm already using them but I don't feel that's enough.

Comment: @arieljannai Lots of local variables might be a sign that you need to break the function into several smaller functions.

Comment: Unfortunately (or luckily?) that's not the case - it's usually when I have some variables and I want to track them relatively quickly in a loop, to see that they change as I expected :)

Comment: I eventually came up with a solution that for it I will only have to set a single expression and only one time :)